# How was this animation made?

Tags: animation, canvas

i found an interesting effect on this site: https://iohk.io/

If you move your mouse around the effect will follow and change its colors, im really fascinated and wonder if there is a term for this kind of effect i can look into so i can learn how this was done.

While checking the source code i found the term "canvas", but its a huge topic.

Im not a developer myself and only know HTML/CSS right now, so please keep this in mind when answering.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you find anything or any clue regarding this effect please must share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

That is the site from the creator, i haven't look in to it that much but all the information you need should be there.

You can use the menu to the right to change the way it looks.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the page I initially thought of WebGL. On inspecting the page my suspicions were confirmed.

The page you linked to is using a [ParticlesJS](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) which looks like a library over WebGL. Given you are not a developer then this may be a little beyond you.